# Highstock --- logarithmic yAxis does not work for negative columns

Tags: highcharts

I tried to plot a column chart with positive and negative values. I intended to dynamically change the yAxis type to logarithmic when the data are too skewed. What is desired for a logarithmic yAxis is that it has two directions. For example, one direction has ticks `[0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100, 1k]`, the other has ticks `[-0.1, -1, -100]`, depending on what the data are like. This is what I used for the chart load event:

```
events: {
    load: function(){
        var s = this.series[0],
            d = s.data,
            minSize = 99999,
            size;
        for (var i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
            if (d[i].y < 0)
                d[i].update({color: '#FF0000'}, false, false);
            size = Math.abs(d[i].y);
            if (size < minSize) 
                minSize = size; 
        }
        if (s.dataMax/minSize > 20 || Math.abs(s.dataMin)/minSize > 20) {
            this.yAxis[0].update({
                type: 'logarithmic' 
            })  
        }
    }
}
```

I found that highstock/highcharts won't generate what I want. All the negative values are skipped and only positive ones are recognized, i.e., only one direction of the yAxis is drawn.

A guess is that highstock/highcharts calls a log(y) function to compute log values, ignoring negatives, but I don't know if there is a workaround.

If I use a log function by myself, compute the values and draw the chart, the ticks can't be correct, because the axis type is linear, which is not what I want.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Probably not the best answer but you could re-write the highcharts source to check if val is negative or not. If positive do what it normally does. If negative have it do all the other math it needs and then multiply the resulting `log(y)` by -1. This might do what you want.

Comment: I ended up with a solution like this:

1. construct two arrays, positives and negatives, and turn the values in negatives to their absolute values;

2. draw the chart with two panels, each with a y axis and a series, one for positives and the other for negatives. For the panel with negatives, reverse the y axis, making it look like the values are negative.

3. write a formatter function for tooltips, so that the displays are correct.

It works OK, but it would be better if highcharts' log scale axis supports negative values, or am I missing something?

Comment: Highcharts logarithmic axis doesn't support negative values. You can create an idea on [uservoice](http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-general) - we are trying to implement most common ideas.